# Fabric - Run a command locally before and after all tasks complete

Tags: python, fabric

I'm attempting to announce deployment start and end in my fabric script. Feels like this should be easy, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.

```
env.hosts = ['www1', 'www2', 'www3', 'www4']


def announce_start(): 
    # code to connect to irc server and announce deployment begins
    pass


def announce_finish(): 
    # code to connect to irc server and announce deployment finishes
    pass


def deploy():
    # actual deployment code here
    pass
```

Here's what I've tried:

If I make my deploy task contain 'announce_start' and 'announce_finish'. It will attempt to run all those tasks on each server.

```
def deploy(): 
    announce_start()
    # actual deployment code here
    announce_finish()
```

If I decorate announce_start() and announce_end() with @hosts('localhost'), it runs it on localhost, but still four times. One for each host.

As I was typing this, I finally got it to work by using the decorator @hosts('localhost') on announce_start/end and the fab command:

```
fab announce_start deploy announce_end
```

But this seems a bit hacky. I'd like it all wrapped in a single deploy command. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fabric.api.execute, e.g.

```
def announce_start(): 
    # code to connect to irc server and announce deployment begins
    pass

def announce_finish(): 
    # code to connect to irc server and announce deployment finishes
    pass

@hosts(...)
def deploy_machine1():
    pass

@hosts(...)
def deploy_machine2():
    pass

def deploy():
    announce_start()
    execute(deploy_machine1)
    execute(deploy_machine2)
    announce_finish()
```

and then just invoke fab deploy

Comment: execute() was helpful, thanks!   Ended up making deploy only run non localhost and then another silent_deploy which ran on all hosts. Still seems funky but it works.

Comment: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/execution.html#leveraging-execute-to-access-multi-host-results