# Does Fabric have a way to run code before and after task execution?

Tags: python, fabric

I have a `fabfile` with a significant number of tasks, which the user can use to compose different sequences.

I would like to give the user some output before and after executing their selected tasks (and possibly offer interaction).

A simple way to do this would be to register pre- and post- methods that could, amongst other things, examine the task list.

Is this possible in Fabric (without modifying all existing tasks)?

Comment: This is different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828248/fabric-run-a-command-locally-before-and-after-all-tasks-complete because that question considers only a single task.

Comment: After a quick look at fabric's source code (`main` function essentially) I think's you'll need to fork Fabric to get this behaviour (specially the "examine the task list" part).

Answer (score 0):

I just needed something similar to this and noticed `env.tasks`, which keeps a list of tasks that should be run. The [docs say](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/usage/env.html#tasks) it is there just for informational purposes, but you can change it to include tasks not passed via the CLI and it will actually execute them!

```py
env.tasks.append("bar")
```

Calling `fab foo` will effectively run `foo` and then `bar`.